# PHP Memcached string size exceeds

Tags: php, memcached, telnet

The following code

```
$memcached = new Memcached();

$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$data = json_encode(array(
        'string1' => md5(time()),
        'string2' => md5(time())
));

var_dump($memcached->set('foo', $data, 300));
```

is working just fine

```
# telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
# get foo
VALUE foo 0 91
{"string1":"884e036fd865cac1ef26b5f7a920c2c2","string2":"884e036fd865cac1ef26b5f7a920c2c2"}
```

but when I add a third line

```
$data = json_encode(array(
        'string1' => md5(time()),
        'string2' => md5(time()),
        'string3' => md5(time())
));

var_dump($memcached->set('foo', $data, 300));
```

it produces the following

```
# get foo
VALUE foo 16 63
x«V*.)ÊÌK7T²RJ322J11KL6M4I4OM¶°H57·4716I5Oµ0NSÒ*6"E±11krW&z
```

I guess memcached is compressing the value somehow, but why isn't it reverting it on get?

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: How to solve what? Have you tried to retrieve it in the php?

Comment: I need to have a JSON string in the end. Currently it's not JSON as you can see.

Comment: Have you tried retriving the data with PHP?

Comment: @Aley: it's not JSON in telnet, since no one guaranteed you a format the client (php extension) stores it.

Comment: @zerkms well its JSON with 2 strings, but some compressed stuff with 3 strings. So it stores it in JSON

Comment: @Putr PHP is working fine. I guess the answere of Baba is correct. I tried to retrive the data via node.js and had the same result. So I thougth it is something else.

Comment: @Aley: an arbitrary client is free to use any format, even gzip.

Comment: @zerkms Do you know what PHP is using to compress the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes because `cli` and `php` are using different options

```
 Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION is true by default
```

[From PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php)

> Enables or disables payload compression. When enabled, item values longer than a certain threshold (currently 100 bytes) will be compressed during storage and decompressed during retrieval transparently.

[Memcached::set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php)

> The value can be any valid PHP type except for resources, because those cannot be represented in a serialized form. If the **Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION** option is turned on, the serialized value will also be compressed before storage.

It compresses the data after specific length ... that is why when you try to get the data from telnet you don't see that `json` but rather the `compressed version`

Answer (score 1):

According to the sources: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/php_memcached.c#L2918 the compression can be either `fastlz` or `zlib`

Its value is specified by `memcached.compression_type` configuration directive (https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/php_memcached.c#L298)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.configuration.php#ini.memcached.compression-type